# Como puedo hacer un parametro opcional y no obligatorio en crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, parametros

Hola buen dia estoy trabajando con crystal reports

Tengo una duda como puedo pasar un parametro "opcional " y que no sea obligatorio

Mi parametro es DocUnidad@

Si me pudieran ayudar Gracias!

Hola buen dia estoy trabajando con crystal reports

Tengo una duda como puedo pasar un parametro "opcional " y que no sea obligatorio

Mi parametro es DocUnidad@